# sqlite - how to insert a record using a subselect

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE group_members(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, group_id integer, member_id integer, FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES users(id));
```

I'm trying to insert a record into the `group_members` table by selecting the value for `group_id` from the `user` table, and then passing in a value for the `member_id`.

```
 insert into group_members (group_id, member_id) 
 values (select id from users where code ='12345' and location='multiple', 281);
```

Where 281 is the member id I'm trying to pass in.

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Error: near "select": syntax error

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd have to check its docs to see whether SQLite accepts subqueries in the value list, but if it does then I would expect you to need to enclose the subquery in its own parentheses.

Comment: Try this: `INSERT INTO group_members(group_id, member_id) VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM users WHERE code = '12345' AND location = 'multiple'), 281)` (not sure if SQLite supports this, but it's where I'd start).

Answer (score 8):

Subqueries must be written in parentheses. The parentheses in your queries already belong to the VALUES clause, so you need another pair:

```
INSERT INTO group_members (group_id, member_id)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE code ='12345' AND location='multiple'), 281);
```

Alternatively, use the other form of the INSERT statement that uses a query instead of the VALUES clause:

```
INSERT INTO group_members (group_id, member_id)
SELECT id, 281 FROM users WHERE code ='12345' AND location='multiple';
```